# "Mobile homes" in American and British English

Tags: difference, vocabulary, american-english, british-english

I'm always getting these types of mobile homes mixed up. Could someone please explain the difference between the following?

1. A ***mobile home***. Is this any home that can be towed by a car? Is this commonly used in both dialects?
2. In the US: ***recreational vehicle*** sometimes called ***an RV***.
   Which of the two names is more common in the US? Are British  people familiar with this term?  If not, what's the most common name for this type of home in the the UK?
3. A ***caravan***, either the colourful gypsy caravan, or the British English one. I don't think Americans use this term. What would it be called in the US? Is it No.4?
4. A ***trailer*** is this also another name for a "recreational vehicle"? What's the difference?
5. In Italy the term ***‘il camper’*** is used for most types of holiday homes driven by motor vehicles. Do British people and Americans use this term? What is the difference between a *camper* and a *caravan*? Is one term more outdated than the other?

Comment: What about the term ***roulotte***?:https://www.google.it/search?q=roulotte+significato&biw=1536&bih=759&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjrt9ayzqrQAhXCaxQKHa52CGIQ_AUIBigB&dpr=1.25#tbm=isch&q=roulotte+

Comment: Usually called an RV, rarely called a "recreational vehicle". A *trailer* has no motor of its own. It is attached to a pickup truck or powerful SUV. Yes, *camper* is used in AmE; it has fold-out tents and awnings.

Comment: I'd also be interested in the Australian version.  Don't they pull a *Fifth wheel* with a *Ute*?

Comment: @Chenmunka - is "roulotte" used in AmE or BrE as far as you know?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner: No, not as far as I know.

Comment: @Chenmunka in AmE, a "fifth wheel" is a type of trailer / camper that is towed behind a pickup truck, where the living quarters extend over the top of the truck bed ([for example](http://www.campingearth.com/images/fifthwheel-small.jpg), you can also see the anchor in the truck bed - another typical feature).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can give you a British English definition as I own such vehicles...

A *caravan* is a trailer towed by a car:

[image: Caravan]

A *camper van* (or *campervan*) is a van of ~1 ton converted for sleeping & cooking.  These are typically VW Transporters or Mazda Bongos.  There are still huge numbers of lovingly preserved VW campervans on the roads (I have a classic T2 and a T5):

[image: Campervan]

A *Motorhome* is a purpose built vehicle, larger than a campervan.  These are coachbuilt onto a commercial chassis.  The chassis are usually Peugeot or Fiat.  They come in varying sizes but are rarely more than 3tons:

[image: Motorhome]

You will find people "in the scene" who get very picky about how their vehicles are described.  Some people will get upset if you refer to their motorhome as a camper for example.

We British do recognise the term *RV* as being an American equivalent.  However, in Britain, when applied to British vehicles, the term is usually only used for the very large:

[image: Large RV]

Comment: Excellent answer, so for instance calling a caravan a "camper" is completely wrong?.

Comment: @Mari-LouA:  Calling a caravan a *van* for short is acceptable.  Calling a caravan a *camper* may irritate a purist.  Most users of all of these vehicles are pretty laid back though - only being pedantic about terminology when discussing their prides and joy with the like-minded.

Comment: And a *motorhome* is the British equivalent  of an American RV, correct?

Comment: @Mari-LouA:  Yes, correct.

Comment: As far as I know a "trailer" is always a generic term for anything that you attach to the back of another vehicle (when you say the term in isolation at least to a British person they'd think of something more like http://www.towbarswales.co.uk/wpimages/wpa23d1f21_05_06.jpg ). But I sometimes hear Americans talking about "trailer parks", so presumably where the context is clear it can be used to specifically refer to what we Brits would call "caravans". In British English there's also a "static caravan" which is a caravan that CAN be towed but is designed to stay in one place most of the time.

Comment: @Mari-LouA 'Motorhome' is used in AmE as well, at least in the northeast.

Comment: You missed *mobile home*, which are often not very mobile at all.

Comment: I also missed *Fifth Wheel* and *Dayvan*, also other common terms like *Hippy Wagon* and *Gin Palace*.  I could go on...

Comment: @TRiG: I have never heard mobile home used in British English.

Comment: @JackAidley: *Mobile Home* is widely used in British English.  However, as TRIG suggests, they aren't very mobile.  Often found in seaside resorts as weekend retreats.

Comment: @Chenmunka: I know those as caravans not mobile homes.

Comment: @JackAidley:  You don't need a crane and a low loader to move a caravan -- https://www.onthemarket.com/for-sale/mobile-home/uk/

Comment: @Chenmunka: *shrug* Different parts of the country clearly use different names then; as I say I know those as caravans.

Answer (score 11):

In American English...

A *mobile home* is a generic term for a purpose-built "vehicle", designed to be lived in and transported around. It may be either self propelled, or a towed trailer (hence the scare quotes on vehicle). A mobile home necessarily includes sleeping quarters, a toilet, and (usually) a bathing facility. They also have specialized connections for hooking up to gas, water, or electricity points. The important connotation here is *something able to be easily moved, and suitable to live in long term*.

An *RV* is necessarily self propelled, and fully capable of being driven legally on highways or interstates. This is not to be confused with other recreational vehicles (e.g. ATVs, dirt bikes, snowmobiles, etc.); while that's what RV stands for, usage of the full words to mean *a vehicle you can live in* is extremely rare. An RV is a fully fledged *mobile home*.

A *motorhome* is the same thing as an *RV*.

A *trailer* is necessarily not self propelled, and must be towed by another vehicle, possibly requiring a commercial grade cargo truck to move. This term is rather generic, though, because trailers vary greatly in size and quality. Trailers are not necessarily fully fledged *mobile homes*, but we do sometimes use the term *trailer home* to indicate a large, nice, or more permanent trailer, which is a proper *mobile home*. The term *trailer park* refers to a dedicated piece of land for (many) people to lease and live on, permanently, with appropriate utility connections. *Trailer* is often - but not necessarily - used in a pejorative sense. People who live in *trailer parks* are generally viewed as poor, uneducated, and uncultured; they're *trailer trash*. *Mobile home* and *RV* do not permit this negative connotation, and if someone makes a point of telling you they live in a *trailer **home***, then they're usually signalling that they are not *trailer trash*.

A *camper* is a specific kind of trailer. It is small, able to be towed by a standard car or truck, and used for traveling or camping outdoors. It is not suitable for living in permanently, and usually does not have toilet and bathing facilities. *Campers* may also have sections which expand and collapse, such as the top piece of the *camper van* in Chenmunka's answer. We don't use the term *camper van*, though; that specific vehicle is extremely rare, even unheard of.

A *caravan* is not something you live in. We use this term as a synonym of *convoy*, but with a more folksy or antiquated connotation, as opposed to the industrial or military one of *convoy*. It evokes imagery of an old fashioned line of carts traveling along and containing a troupe of performers, tradesmen, or pioneers.

One of the key differences between the British uses is that the American terms don't connote specific brands at all. We are also not picky about swapping different terms around; indeed, which one you hear used predominately depends on the regional dialect. Taking dialects into account, *mobile home*, *RV*, and *trailer* are roughly interchangeable. Yes, even though I just said *RV* and *trailer* technically are exclusive categories, it is possible to hear them used to mean the same thing (a generic *mobile home*), depending on where you are in the US.

Comment: I have to take issue with your description of *mobile home.*  In the middle U.S., this is unequivocally a complete structure, with bedrooms, kitchen, bathroom, hallways, all the full size one would expect in a permanent frame-built house.  It is designed to be a permanent residence for a small family.  The *mobile* part comes at a fair degree of difficulty of expense.  The structure often has to be partially disassembled, then jacked or lifted by a crane onto a wheel base, where it can then be hooked onto a commercial towing vehicle, i.e. a semi-truck.

Comment: I was born in the Midwest and that's simply false. If you told people there *I live in a mobile home*, the definition that springs to mind first is *RV* or *trailer*, not the technical term of art you're suggesting.

Comment: Simply fascinating.  I too was born in the mid-west and have lived throughout the Great Lakes region.  I've had aunts, uncles, cousins, and co-workers that did live in mobile homes, and these were definitely not trailers or RVs.  I agree wholly with this note from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_home):  "Mobile homes share the same historic origins as travel trailers, but today the two are very different in size and furnishings, with travel trailers being used primarily as vacation or temporary homes."

Comment: I'm from the Great Lakes region, lived for a decade in California, and now live in the Great Plains. Everywhere I have lived, a *mobile home* is a prefabricated *house* —as seen in all the top hits of this [Google Image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=mobile+home&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS696US697&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjgyuyxk6vQAhXHTCYKHTtJDfIQ_AUICSgC&biw=1484&bih=954). They're mobile primarily in the sense that they are built in one location, and then moved to their eventual (probably permanent) installation. What is described in your first paragraph is a *motor* home.

Comment: @1006a: I think there is more of a distinction between mobile homes and prefabricated houses.  A mobile home generally has its own frame & suspension, and could be moved (even if it never is in practice).  In many states, they require a license as a motor vehicle, and are generally found in mobile home parks, where the parking space is leased.  Prefabricated houses are hauled on trailers, placed on their own permanent foundations, and for tax purposes are treated exactly as a stick-built house. And both are distinct from an RV, motor home, or camping trailer.

Comment: Also in American usage, a 'camper' is often a living place that is carried on the bed of a pickup truck.  It can range from a simple "camper shell" that's just a roof over the bed, to a large structure that extends over the cab and has stove, toilet, sleeping places, &c.

Comment: @jamesqf I imagine you're correct from a licensing (and sales) point of view; however, in casual usage I think folks use them fairly interchangeably. See, for example, [this explanation](http://www.drysideproperty.com/mobile%20vs%20manuf%20vs%20modular.html) of *mobile* vs *manufactured* vs *modular* homes (distinct regulatory differences, but "*Mobile Home* is often used interchangeably with the term *Manufactured Home*"; note also that this  website's company is located in Washington State, so another geographic data point).

Comment: I lived in a trailer park in Ohio from 2011 to 2015. It was a neighborhood of "mobile homes" formally, "trailers" more colloquially—manufactured wooden structures on a large metal frame with wheels (ours was small at 14' x 70'). As @cobaltduck said, they are not truly that mobile, since they usually have a number of connections to the ground: plumbing, electrical lines, plastic/aluminum skirting that reaches from the bottom of the home to the ground. In our park, most trailers also had a free-standing deck or carport right outside the front door.

Comment: There seems to be some disagreement about what a  *mobile home* is in some parts of the US. Could either the OP, or @1006a, or Colbalt duck, or anyone please modify this answer or post a new answer  which points out that a "mobile home" in the US  need't be transportable, but can be (semi-) permanent structure.  Thanks!

Comment: @cobaltduck an answer specifying that not all mobile homes in the US have an inbuilt motor or can be towed by a car needs top be added. A picture or two would be nice too.  Thanks.

Comment: In Florida, where “manufactured” homes are fairly common, calling them a “mobile” home is somewhat acceptable but uncommon — however, calling them “trailers” is considered derogatory but correct. A “double wide” or “triple wide” manufactured home is less likely to be called a trailer and almost never a mobile home, however.

Comment: Having grown up an a **mobile home** ([as pictured at the top of this wikipeda page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_home)) in a **trailer park**, I understand there are regional as well as national differences in the terms.